# Как сохранить все строчки HEADERS из POSTMAN?

Tags: api, header, postman

В процессе тестирования API необходимо сохранять из POSTMAN результаты запросов, в том числе headers. Как проще всего это делать - сохранять headers? Скриншоты - не вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через консоль постмана ([подробно тут есть](https://skalolaskovy.ru/internet/577-postman-headers))